# AWS response times out on Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postman

I have an EC2 instance running a Go server on port 8090.
In my EC2 instance, I added a security group which accepts inbound requests from all protocols and all ports.

I created a new user on AWS, and added the Access Key and Secret Key (under Auth) of that user while making a new request through Postman.

I then tried to make a request, but the request always times out.

How can I connect to EC2 server through Postman? Am I doing something wrong?

Response:

[image]

Comment: Is your EC2 in the public subnet and is the port open?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the ec2 server under the default subnet zone, then its not subnet connectivity issue.

you need to check the following

1. is your go server listing to all addresses or just local address
   you can use the following command

> ```
> netstat -anlp | grep 8090
> ```

if you see 0.0.0.0 then you're good otherwise you need to change the listener

2. check if your OS has a firewall, if you use centos for example:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-stop-and-disable-firewalld-on-centos-7/

Comment: updated ny question. no firewall is running on server.

Comment: Did you check the listener port ?